If particles do not have definite properties before measurement in entanglement, what are they?
It is said that in quantum entanglement, a photon does not have definite properties before measurement. I have two questions.

Is this true for all interpretations of quantum mechanics?

what does it mean for a photon to not have definite properties before measurement? Is it still a photon? If it is in a superposition, what does this look like in reality?



If it is in a superposition, what does this look like in reality? The only way to know what something “looks like” is to measure it, and then it is no longer in superposition.

So we don’t know what it looks like then? It seems very fine tuned because the act of measurement changes what happens in some interpretations of QM

Yes, measurement collapses the superposition to an eigenstate.

Ah you keep deleting comments it’s hard to keep track. So are you saying we don’t know what it looks like then before collapse?

I deleted a response to a comment that you deleted or edited because it no longer made sense.

Ah okay. I just don’t understand or am trying to understand how the particle looks like in a superposition. I edited a comment earlier I think yeah

Please reread my first comment.

So are you saying that we basically cannot know what it looks like since measurement would disrupt it? There are things in the world we can’t directly ever see like dinosaurs. We can only see their fossils but we can still make a model of how they would look like. I don’t understand why we can’t do the same for a particle perhaps based on other evidence. Do we just not have that evidence?

Quantum particles are not anything like dinosaurs. The wavefunction before measurement models/predicts what we will measure, with what probability.

Yeah I get that, I was just trying to visualize how it looks in my head. But if it’s only probabilities, it becomes hard to do, since multiple measurement outcomes are possible. So something about the nature of going from those possible outcomes to one outcome doesn’t make sense. I guess we don’t know

I was just trying to visualize how it looks in my head. My advice: Don’t try. Or, if you must visualize something, visualize either the wavefunction or the probability density evolving. As an example, look at the time-dependent wavefunction for a superposition of the lowest two energy states of a particle in a 1D box. You can probably find that online somewhere, or write a short program to show it.

When asking questions about QM, it would be helpful if you mentioned whether you are currently studying QM or just have an interest in it. The answers you’ll get are likely to be different in terms of how technical or non-technical they are.

You should explain what you mean by " what does this look like in reality" for an entangled photon before measurement, or any quantum object described by a wave function before measurement. What do expect to happen, when you" look at it"?

Physicists use the equations of quantum physics to make predictions, but what is happening in reality to bring those predictions about is controversial.
Some of the interpretations say that there is no account of what is happening in reality in quantum experiments and we should just make predictions using the equations, e.g. - the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations. Since conducting an experiment properly requires adjusting it to produce the appropriate conditions in the experiment this approach makes no sense. Advocates of such interpretations would say there is no account of what an entangled particle looks like. It's a bit odd to describe an idea that claims quantum theory doesn't describe reality as an interpretation of quantum theory.
Other interpretations modify the equations of quantum theory, such as the spontaneous collapse or pilot wave theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10761
The pilot wave theory claims the world around us is a set of particles that interacts with the wave function and so the particle is in some particular state but we don't know what it is. The spontaneous collapse theory claims that the particle is described by a wave function that sometimes collapses to be narrowly peaked in the relevant measurable quantities, so what the particle looks like depends on whether the collapse has happened. These theories produce different predictions than quantum theory, which makes it a bit weird to call them interpretations of quantum theory rather than alternatives to it.
Neither of those theories currently reproduces the results of relativistic quantum field theories that are used to describe quantum experiments where relativistic effects are important:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
So for some of entanglement experiments such as those involving photons the situation is even murkier.
If we take quantum equations of motion seriously as a description of reality, then each system is described by a set of operators called observables that can be represented by matrices. Suppose you have a set of systems all prepared in the same way in a state $\rho$ (represented by a Hermitian operator whose trace is 1) and you measure them in some sequence and compare the results. In some of those situations each time you measure an observable $\hat{X}$ you get the same result and the observable is said to be sharp. But in some situations you can get different results as a result of measuring $\hat{X}$ for identically prepared systems and $\hat{X}$ is said to be unsharp. You can do experiments in which you apply some operation depending on the value of $\hat{X}$ when $\hat{X}$ is unsharp and you get different results depending on what you did to each value: quantum interference. So there are multiple versions of the system one for each possible value of $\hat{X}$ and they can interfere with one another:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
When information is copied out of a system undergoing interference the interference is suppressed: this process is called decoherence. So the different versions of the system evolve autonomously after that and they are sorted into layers each of which looks a bit like the universe as described by classical physics, so there are parallel universes:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This way of explaining quantum experiments is commonly called the many worlds interpretation (MWI). In the MWI you can describe an entangled system in terms of its observables. The observables of each system carry quantum information about the system it is entangled with, but you can't get it by measuring that system alone so it is called locally inaccessible information (LIA). The observables of the entangled systems are unsharp so they exist in multiple versions but have LIA that can be carried in decoherent systems because it can't be copied out by interactions. The LIA produces correlations when results of measurements on the entangled systems are compared:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
So the entangled particle before the comparison exists in multiple versions that get matched up after the measurement in the MWI.
